# JAWS starts announcing content in the middle of the page when navigating via form submission in IE11

Tags: html, forms, accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I'm encountering something bizarre in which a page with a form and fairly minimal layout is read correctly by JAWS 16 and 18 in IE11 on initial load. However, when that page is loaded from the action of a form on another page (via either `GET` or `POST`), JAWS will skip the standard page overview description ("page has 5 regions...") and immediately announce the content of some seemingly irrelevant `<p>` tag in the middle of the page. I've noticed a similar effect on some other pages as well, always when reached via a form submission.

These are very basic layouts and there isn't any JavaScript being triggered on load that could be adjusting focus in any way. No problems in either Chrome or Firefox.

Anyone encounter an issue like this before?

Comment: Do you have repeated text on those pages? There is an option to skip repeated text (for example, the top menu) on web pages, which is turned on by default. What is bizarre is different behavior in different browsers, though.

Comment: There is some repeated text in the header, but the main content isn't the same. It also starts the announcing mid-way through that content, so if there are four paragraphs in the main body of the page (all unique to that page), JAWS starts announcing on the third.

Answer (score 0):

There should be nothing wrong with Dan's coding. In my exactly similar case, both the main page and the popup page codes work beautifully. The problem happens in JAWS that randomly and briefly reads a paragraph written with p tag in the middle of the popup first before reading from the beginning of the popup. It turns out that is a false positive of JAWS since the same popup is well read with NVDA that perfectly starts from the beginning of the popup page. I have been using JAWS 2020, and wonder if JAWS newer versions would get corrected especially on this popup feature.

Answer (score 0):

+1 I see this too

Following a `submit` on a multi page form, when the next page loads, NVDA sometimes will commence reading from part way through the page, rather than from the top, or at least from the first unique part of the new page.

A bug in NVDA, an issue with the page?

Given this seems to be happening with JAWS also, I wonder if a common coder practice (no idea what practice) is somehow tripping screen readers into commencing output in a way different to that which they use on a new unrelated URL?